# Custom header content animate while scrolling in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have created custom header but I don't know how to animate while scrolling.

Please check below image and let me know how to animate while scrolling.
This animated header in [Fotmob](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/fotmob-live-soccer-scores/id488575683?mt=8) app.

[image]

Comment: so you don't have any code? you want us to do that for you? It is hard to know what you are working with, it is a header or navigation bar?

Comment: you can use ->
 scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) function and update title

Comment: One of these libraries might help you achieve something like this.

This one is the closest to what you are looking for.
https://github.com/vicentesuarez/Swift-FlexibleHeightBar

Here are some other options....
https://github.com/telly/TLYShyNavBar
https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/HidingNavigationBar
https://github.com/andreamazz/AMScrollingNavbar

Comment: Hi it's called sticky header you can do this thing using stroyboard and with out storyboard too. please check this here is a good stuff you can achieved this thing :-   
  https://medium.com/@jeremysh/creating-a-sticky-header-for-a-uitableview-40af71653b55
https://github.com/gskbyte/GSKStretchyHeaderView

Answer (score 2):

First of all add header view as UIvVew and add UIScrollView or UITableView below headerView same as screenshot and follow below step.

[image]

1. set a fixed height constraint to the header view (125 for example) and attach it to top, left and right.
2. make the UIScrollView below to use all the available space so set to zero top, bottom, left and right constraints.
3. connect the header view height constraint to the ViewController in order to have something like:

   ```
    @IBOutlet var headerViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
   ```
4. set the UIScrollView delegate to the ViewController
5. declare two properties to limit the maximum and the minimum height of the header view, fox example:

   ```
   let headerViewMaxHeight: CGFloat = 125
   let headerViewMinHeight: CGFloat = 44 + UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height
   ```
6. The entire workaround is based on update the header view height constraint while the UIScrollView is scrolling, so let’s implement the UIScrollViewDelegate and the most important delegate for our case, the scrollViewDidScroll:

   ```
   func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

       let headerViewMinHeight: CGFloat = 44 + UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height

       let yPos = mainScrollView.contentOffset.y
       let newHeaderViewHeight: CGFloat = headerViewHeightConstraint.constant - yPos

       if newHeaderViewHeight > headerViewMaxHeight {
           // Here, Manage Your Score Format View
           headerViewHeightConstraint.constant = max(headerViewMaxHeight, newHeaderViewHeight)

       } else if newHeaderViewHeight < headerViewMinHeight {

       headerViewHeightConstraint.constant = headerViewMinHeight

       } else {

           headerViewHeightConstraint.constant = newHeaderViewHeight
           scrollView.contentOffset.y = 0 // block scroll view

       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I have created the same, Check the below image

[image: MyFriendList]

**Overview**

1. TableView
2. Sample MVVM pattern
3. Swift 5.0 above
4. Xcode 11 above

Find the GIT URL for code

[HeaderAnimation](https://github.com/Sivabalaa/HeaderAnimation)

Comment: Thank you for creating a sample project, I'll check it.